# How to make a query with AND and OR operators?

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Persons WHERE {1}='A' AND {2}!='A' AND {3}!='A'"
```

and I have the following task: to get all entries from table Person where {1} is A and {2} or {3} are not 'A', i.e. ABC, ABA, etc. Now I can get only ABC, ABB, etc, not ABA. Please, help me.

Comment: Your description of what you want and your example are contradictory.  In ABA, {2} is not 'A', so it satisfied your condition.  Your query seems to satisfy your example.

Comment: Do you mean where {1} is A and at least one of {2} or {3} are not 'A'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Parenthesis to give Precedence to the logical operators

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Persons WHERE {1}='A' AND  ({2}!='A' OR {3}!='A')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic-wise simplification, compare {2} and {3} together?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Persons
WHERE {1}='A' AND {2}+{3} != 'AA'
```

Without parenthesis, you can check this out [Operator Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Persons
WHERE {1}='A' AND {2}!='A'
   OR {1}='A' AND {3}!='A'
```